# django south broke my db (can't drop constraint)

Tags: python, database, django, postgresql, django-south

I wanted to add a table and a foreign key to that table. Initially I had:

```
class VirtualMachine(models.Model):
    ...
```

I then changed that to:

```
class OperatingSystem(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class VirtualMachine(models.Model):
    operating_system = models.ForeignKey(OperatingSystem, default=1)
```

and I wanted to make an entry so that 1 would be "WindowsXP". South didn't like that, though, so I changed the last line to:

```
    operating_system = models.ForeignKey(OperatingSystem, null=True)
```

That worked ok. After that migration I added the "WindowsXP" entry and changed it back to:

```
    operating_system = models.ForeignKey(OperatingSystem, default=1)
```

I did `python manage.py schemamigration app --auto`, which worked fine, then `python manage.py migrate app`, which froze. Froze!

I cancelled it and went into `psql`. I couldn't do `SELECT * FROM app_virtualmachine;` - that would hang, although getting stuff from other tables would not. I couldn't even select just a column from there. I tried dropping the constraint South added but also no good. What gives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah I think the table got locked or something. I restarted postgres and then could do stuff manually to the table and rescue it.